# Unable to call lambda function URI with file form-data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda and enabled its function URL together with auth type of AWS_IAM. I then created a user with the policy required following this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html).

I could call the function URL in postman with

1. Authorization type = AWS Signature
2. AccessKey, SecretKey, Region, Service = lambda

However, when I call the function URL with postman (added in a file in form-data), postman returned 403:

```
{
    "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."
}
```

However, if I remove the file parameter in form-data and resend, this message does not appear. But does that mean function URL on lambda does not support form-data?

[image]
[image]

Comment: In web postman, you were also sending the file?

Comment: Ah on web postman also facing similar issue when I correctly select the file. The previous file path was invalid, and the function URL was able to be called.

Comment: Enabling CORS wouldn’t change anything ?

Comment: I've enabled CORS but same error message. I am thinking does the file affect the computation of the AWS signature?